# Lag function within a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, lag

I want to use a lag function within a for-loop in csv file to copy certain attributes on the above row. Below is a code I wrote.

```
pa = rep(NA, 2000)
ss = rep(NA, 2000)

for (i in 1:1949) {
  ss[i] <- subset(csv, attribute1 = i)
  pa[i] <- lag(ss$attribute2, 1)
}
```

But it returns error codes,

> Error in hasTsp(x) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL 
>   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

How to fix this issue?

Comment: `i in 1 to 1949` ? You mean `i in 1:1949` ?

Comment: Just use `tail(varname, -1)` instead. `lag` doesn't do what you think it does. It is for time series objects.This would probably be `pa <- c(NA, tail(varname, -1))` or maybe `pa[1:1949] <- c(NA, tail(varname, -1))[1:1949]`.

Comment: Oh that's a typo. Thanks. I wrote a right code on R though.

Comment: also, what is `csv`? Your code doesn't run, make it a reproducible example....

Comment: @Imo let me try. Give me a second.

Comment: @rbm I have a csv file and I just wrote its name as csv

Comment: @EdwardM. There is an edit link to to fix typos and such.

Comment: @lmo It works. Thanks. Btw, can I ask one more? I want to make the result of 'pa' as a one column in csv but not sure how to do it. Using that way, it shows me something worng.

Comment: Read `help("[.data.frame")`. It is worth reading a couple of times, as this is an extremely common tool in R. You will find what you are looking for in the examples.

Comment: @lmo Thanks a lot!